# Spring webSocket - Reject topic subscription based on user rights with IE8 - determineUser() never called

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs, spring-4

I would like to reject subscription according to user permissions. I found the following solution and it helped for browsers that support websocket:

https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/issues/23

the solution is extending DefaultHandshakeHandler and overriding determineUser method.
the issue is - this method is never called when connecting from IE8. 
Would appreciate any help. thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your question is more about how to associate a user with the session. By default the WebSocket session gets the user from the HttpServletRequest during the handshake (i.e. getPrincipal). The DefaultHandshakeHandler does provide a protected method but that only works for the WebSocket transport. So currently the best way to associate a user with the WebSocket session is to to wrap the HttpServletRequest (e.g. in a Filter) and return the user.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security 4 adds support for WebSocket message and subscription protection. You can configure it with Java config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configure(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {

        messages
                .destinationMatchers("/app/your.topic").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyMessage().hasRole("USER");

    }
}
```

This will protect both, subscriptions and messages sent to */app/your.topic* with the role *ROLE_ADMIN*. Another solution would be mapping the subscription in your controller and using the `@PreAuthorize` annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@SubscribeMapping("/your.topic")
public String notifications()  {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The PreAuthorize on a method annotated with SubscribeMapping will not work, as this is only a listener that is called after the subscription is made, in a different thread.

Comment: It only protect the message from user without 'ADMIN' role. How can I protect '/user/A/message' subscription from user B so that only user A can subscribe it